# How can I dynamically add a value to a left absolute positioned element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a left value of 55 pixels to an absolute positioned element. The total left value should equal 465px.

My jQuery code:

```
var position = $('.popover').offset(); 
var leftposition = position.left + 55;

position(leftposition);
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="myElement" style="top: 0; left: 410px;">My Element</div>
```

Not sure how to do this in jQuery. I am also open to doing this in JavaScript.

Comment: Is Sass an option?

Comment: @JonathanRys I use Sass so its welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to get the current value and then add whatever you want to it:

```js
$("#moveit").on("click", ()=> {
  var position = $('.myElement').css("left").replace("px", ""); 
  $('.myElement').css("left", (+position + 55) + "px");
});
```

```css
.myElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myElement">My Element</div>
<button id="moveit">Move it</button>
```